# VirtualBox Lubuntu grub-pc boot loader failed to insall

Tags: grub2, virtualbox, lubuntu

I've seen this error for full-blown installs, but not for an install into VirtualBox, so observations about UEFI and the like don't apply (as far as I can see).

I'm trying to install Lubuntu into VirtualBox. All goes well until the actual package installation starts where, after a while, a message appears saying that grub-pc installation failed (no reason given). I can pick the other options presented (install to a different location, don't install a boot loader, ignore), but clicking on the continue button justs does nothing and I have to force the machine to close down.

There are other VMs installed: Windows XP, Windows 7, Ubuntu Mate, Manjaro. All of these are fine. In fact I did have Lubuntu 15.10 installed as well, but it somehow lost its connection to the internet after upgrading to 16.04. I couldn't solve that one either, so decided to reinstall. All the other VMs are fine.

At one point I was getting some errors about lack of disk space, but I think this is a red herring as it ocurred not on a full install but on an attempt to recover a failed install.  And the VM reported a Virtual Hard Disk of 8Gb with only 3Gb used.

Any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Best regards

Peter

Comment: Can you, perhaps, attempt to do the install normally and, when it reaches the point where the grub-install failed, select "Don't install a boot-loader"? Then, once you've powered down the (almostly completely installed) machine, run it again from the live-cd and do a manual grub-install?

Answer (score 2):

Found [this similar post on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/845630/ubuntu-server-14-04-lts-grub-fails-to-install-on-a-vm/845720) with an answer by [Marcello Mönkemeyer](https://superuser.com/users/393869/marcello-m%c3%b6nkemeyer)

> The problem actually was, that the `/boot` partition wasn't created, even though it was shown in the UI. It's still possible to get everything running with the guided partitioning, but when you're asked to `Write the changes to the disk?`, you need to go `<Back>` to see a detailed list of all partitions. When clicking `<Next>`, the installation will finally recognise and partition everything correctly and as expected.

Comment: If you already found the answer in another place, either link that place or don't post anything on it at all. Reposting the same answer just clutters things up.